# Reinstalled Vista Limited Connectivity

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-vista, reinstall, dell-inspiron

I have just recently re-installed windows vista on my laptop (Dell 1525).
It used to connect to the wifi fine, but sometimes would only have limited connectivity to the network with no internet access, but would right itself within the next day or two.

However after reinstalling windows it only remains on limited connectivity and cannot get any internet access.

Can anybody help?

Comment: More specific information about the 801.11 mode your using is required to help and the specific WiFI device being used is required to help

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a static set of IP address, subnet mask(usually fills out automatically depending if the IP is class A,b,c) ,default gateway.

and then using a general DNS like the google one which is 8.8.8.8 and 4.4.4.4
and see if that gets you back up and running.

If you don't know how you can follow these steps:
1) Windows key + R - this should pop up the "run" box 
2) in the run box type CMD and hit the enter key - this will open up command prompt
3) in command prompt type ipconfig /all -this will show you your current connection details

keep that window open

now go to your network and sharing center by right clicking on your connection in the bottom of your screen next to the time and selecting open network center.

1) click on "change adapter settings" 
2) right click on the network you are using 
3) select properties on the drop down list
4) untick the box next to the internet protocol version 6  (ipv6)
5) click on the internet protocol version 4 (ipv4) and click the properties button
6) on this screen tick the "use following IP address"
7) IP address: 192.168.0.25
   Subnet mask will fill in automatically (255.255.255.0)
   default gateway you are going to check in the command prompt window in the background    that you left open in section 1 it should look like (192.168.1.1 or 10.0.0.2)

8) in the next area click the "use the following DNS settings"
9) Preffered DNS 8.8.8.8
   alternate DNS 4.4.4.4

Some network set ups require you to have these credentials.
If it works you can find out from your ISP what their DNS servers are and use those details.

If this doesn't help you can revert these actions by simply clicking on "use automatic setting" on both areas.
Then you can look into driver issues, go to the manufacturers website from a different device download the drivers and run them on your laptop.

Hope this helps.